# AES-256-CTR missing on new server with identical PHP version

Tags: php, apache, encryption

Recently had to rebuild a server running a legacy PHP application, and have run into an issue where a cipher we depend on for openssl_decrypt - aes-256-ctr - is missing.

The PHP versions are identical, and the apache versions are both 2.4, but with different patch numbers.

As far as I can tell ctr mode for aes256 is still considered secure, and in fact the underlying openssl install that comes with apache still lists it under `openssl enc ciphers`, so I'm not sure why php would not list it with `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`.

Is there a way to re-enable the cipher on the new server? Why would it be missing since it still is supported by the openssl installation it is using?

**New server (without aes-256-ctr)**

```
PHP: 5.3.24
OpenSSL: 1.1.1c
Apache: 2.4.39 (Win32)
```

**Old server (with aes-256-ctr)**

```
PHP: 5.3.24
OpenSSL: 1.0.1e
Apache: 2.4.4 (Win32)
```

Comment: This [Unsupported cipher method aes-256-ctr #420](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/issues/420) might be interesting for you.

Comment: This question is pretty interesting and I searched for a few hours yesterday. The only thing that it could be is that the openssl version was compiled with FIPS-mode enabled (It seems like a possibility, according to the link above). But even that is not sure since FIPS seems to support CTR mode and you don't really find anything about it.

Comment: I've confirmed that FIPS mode is not enabled by running `openssl md5 test.txt`

Comment: This is off topic but you might want to upgrade from PHP 5.3.24 to a supported version of PHP (7.2 or newer). This will almost certainly accompany an OpenSSL version increase and solve your problem for free.

Comment: As I said, it's a legacy application. PHP upgrade is not an option without massive rewrites

Comment: Plus, doesn't PHP use apache's copy of openssl anyway? It doesn't ship with one

Comment: It uses what your OS provides, not Apache's.

Comment: I am using a newer version of Windows server, how can I find out what the OS is providing?